# Как правильно оформить предложение с вводным словом и тире?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Как правильно оформить предложение?
*а) Селекция пшеницы — наверное, это одно из самых сильных направлений селекции в нашей стране.

б) Селекция пшеницы, наверное, — это одно из самых сильных направлений селекции в нашей стране.*
Думаю, можно оформить и так и так. В моём случае "наверное" относится ко второй части предложения, по интонации и смыслу ближе к нему.

Comment: "Это" нарушает структуру, его надо убрать. Либо поставить "наверное" после "это".

Comment: Занимаюсь расшифровками, поэтому возникают подобные случаи частенько, а менять слова местами не могу. Как сказали, так и расшифровываю))

Comment: Дело в том, что в первом варианте из-за "это" получается не простое предложение, а сложное ("это" не сказуемое, а подлежащее), что сопоставимо с: *Селекция пшеницы. Наверное, это одно из самых сильных направлений селекции в нашей стране.* Вряд ли этого хотели! А второй вариант некорректен. Что за расшифровки? Рукописей?

Comment: Расшифровки аудиозаписей. В данном случае – интервью. Есть такая профессия – транскрибатор, или по-простому – стенограф. Некоторые заказчики просят не менять порядок слов, а там и миллион запинок-заминок, и то, что я оформил в вопросе.

Comment: Интересная профессия. Проблема в том, что люди иногда говорят нарушая грамматику. А как правильно записать, если само предложение некорректно? Посоветовал бы обрезать запись и добавить в вопрос ссылку на аудиофрагмент с этим предложением. Дело в том, что интонация очень важна, потому что она отображается в пунктуации.

Comment: Да, верно, интонация очень важна, и я это очень хорошо понимаю, так как с помощью знаков стараюсь передать её. В данном случае никаких пауз сделано не было. Думаю, предложение, которое произнесли, можно транскрибировать так: "Селекция пшеницы — это, наверное, одно из самых сильных направлений селекции в нашей стране" – и смысл его не изменится. Это не первый подобный случай в практике. Обычно вводное я ставлю после тире, но всё-таки решил задать вопрос))

Comment: Если вводное между подлежащим и сказуемым, то тире не ставится, но тогда "это" нет, потому что оно нарушает такую структуру.